# Looping through tree to create a dictionary_NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, grammar

I'm new to Python and trying to solve a problem looping through a tree in NLTK. I'm stuck on the final output, it is not entirely correct.
I'm looking to create a dictionary with 2 variables and if there is no quantity then add value 1.
This is the desired final output:

{ quantity =1, food =pizza }, {quantity =1, food = coke }
,{quantity =2, food = beers}, {quantity =1, food = sandwich }

Here is my code, any help is much appreaciated!

'''

```
import nltk as nltk
nltk.download()


grammar = r""" Food:{<DT>?<VRB>?<NN.*>+}
                      }<>+{ 
              Quantity: {<CD>|<JJ>|<DT>} 
            """
rp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)


def RegPar(menu):
    grammar = r"""Food:{<DT>?<VRB>?<NN.*>+}
                      }<>+{ 
                  Quantity: {<CD>|<JJ>|<DT>} 
            """
    rp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    output = rp.parse(menu)
    return(output)

Sentences = [ 'A pizza margherita', 'one coke y 2 beers', 'Sandwich']

tagged_array =[]
output_array =[]

for s in Sentences:
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    tags = nltk.pos_tag(tokens)
    tagged_array.append(tags)
    output = rp.parse(tags)
    output_array.append(output)
    print(output)

dat = []

tree = RegPar(output_array)


for subtree in tree.subtrees():
    if subtree.label() == 'Food' or subtree.label() =='Quantity':
         dat.append({(subtree.label(),subtree.leaves()[0][0])})        
print(dat)



##[{('Food', 'A')}, {('Quantity', 'one')}, {('Food', 'coke')}, {('Quantity', '2')}, {('Food', 'beers')}, {('Food', 'Sandwich')}]*
```

'''